# How to use string data from another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a string named label that contains the value 'Next'. I have passed the value to another class but am not able to use it in the Text widget.
I have send the value is this manner.
 `MainButton(label: 'GetStarted',tapEvent: () { }, )`
but not able to use in another class
`class MainButton extends StatefulWidget { const MainButton({Key? key, required String label, required this.tapEvent}) : super(key: key);`
how to use the String label in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when in the life-cycle you are populating the Text(...) Widget. You might need to use SetState( () {} ) to trigger a re-build of the Widget to show the label.

That could be the problem.

Comment: class MainButton extends StatefulWidget {

  const MainButton({Key? key, required String label, required this.tapEvent})
      : super(key: key);
How to print the label string?